# VBA print console output when running script with exec

Tags: excel, vba

I wish I could run a vba script (which calls a python script) without using WaitOnReturn (so it keeps my Excel unblocked) and displaying stdout in real time in a console.
I run the script from Excel 365 on a Windows machine.

I know I can launch script using Run or Exec. As I didn't want to block Excel, I use here Exec.
But I don't manage to display outputs from the script in the console Excel opens.

Any help please ?
Here's my code :

```
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim obj_exec: Set obj_exec = wsh.exec("foo")

While obj_exec.Status = 0 
    Debug.Print obj_exec.StdOut.ReadLine()
Wend
```

I was hoping Debug.Print would work ...